# Outsource function/script permanently

Tags: r

In every Script I paste the same path to get some functions/r-scripts. Is there a possibility to save this path globally and permanently? It should be independently of the workingspace or other loading data paths and should be available on every new R-Session.

Thanks.

Comment: you just described an r package, create your own r package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Place this in your .Rprofile file.  The `messsage` line is optional but will allow you to confirm that .Rprofile was run when you start R.

```
message("Hello")
options("mypath" = "...path goes here...")
```

and then in your script get it using the following which will use that path if the mypath option was defined or the current directory otherwise.  Omit the second argument if you don't want to have a default.

```
getOption("mypath", ".")
```

**2)** You could also just put this in your .Rprofile

```
mypath <- "...your path goes here..."
```

and then just refer to mypath in the script but that will cause `mypath` to clutter up your workspace which you may not want.

**3)** R also will read the environment variables defined in .Renviron so if that file contained:

```
MYPATH="...path goes here..."
```

then the script could get it via `Sys.getenv("MYPATH")` .

See `?Startup` for more information on .Rprofile and .Renviron .

**4)** You could also create an exported shell variable on Linux or environment variable on Windows and then read it in the script using `Sys.getenv` .

Comment: Tried first option but get error Objekt 'mypath' was not found.  Tried this way: source(file.path(mypath, 'functionX.R')). Have put options("mypath", "...path goes here...") in the end of .Rprofile.

Comment: mypath is still not findable. btw: is the name "mypath" a must, or can I choose an other name?

Comment: May be my call is wrong. I use: `source(file.path(getoption('mypath', '.'), 'FunctionX.R'))`

Comment: now it works, but only with "mypath", unfortunatelly.

Comment: There may be some inconsistency between your `getOption` and `options` calls or other error.  `mypath` is no different than any other name.  I have a number of `options` statements in my .Rprofile that all work and none of them are `mypath`.

Comment: One other check you can make is to enter this into R and it will show all the options that you or R have set: `names(options())`